# jQuery - need to remove item from array

Tags: jquery, arrays

My 'listmaker' contains one text box & two buttons. You type an item into the text box, hit "Add Item" and the item is pushed to an array. When you're done, hit finish and a div is populated with a list of your items. Each list item also has a checkbox. I want to remove any list item with a checked checkbox, preferrably by clicking another button to "remove checked items", but not necessary.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
        <title>Listmaker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="add" />
        <button type="button" name="addItem" id="addItem">Add Item</button>
        <button type="button" name="finish" id="finish">Finish</button> 
        </form>
        <div>
            <ol id="list">
            </ol>
            <button type="button" name="lineThrough" id="lineThrough">Remove Checked Items</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var list = [];
        $('#add').focus();

    $('#addItem').click(function() {
        list.push($('#add').val());
        $('#add').val('');
        $('#add').focus();
    });

    $('#finish').click(function() {
        for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        $('#list').append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="unchecked"/>' +list[i]+ '</li>');
        }
    });

});
```

I've tried it a bunch of different ways over the last few hours, and I don't even think I was on the right track so I didn't include my attempt(s) in the code above. I can't wrap my head around how to iterate over the checkboxes and array.remove() the array item of which it's a part. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/GKnHG/1/

We can use the `.splice()` method.

```
$('li').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('input:checked').length) {
     var val = $(this).find("span").html();
     var index = $.inArray(val, list);
     if (index >= 0) {
        list.splice(index, 1);
     }
  }
});
buildList();
```

I moved the list build to another function (`buildList()`), as we call on it when the finish button is clicked, and at the end of the above block.

Basically, we're looping through `each()` of the `li`'s, then checking `if` they have a `:checked` `input` inside them (length would be `0` if there are none).

Once we know we've got a `li` with a checked checkbox, we can get use `.html()` to get a string out of the `span` element, and do a `jQuery.inArray()` check, which returns the index of the value in the array, or `-1` if it can't find any.

`if` it's greater than or equal to zero, we use the `splice()` method to delete the array item at that index. The second argument is how many items to delete.

Comment: Good work, but isn't this overly complicated for a removing of an element from the DOM and list? jQuery has a lot of helper methods for achieving the same thing like .is() and .remove(); instead of splicing a list?

Comment: checking the `length` property is a bit quicker than calling `.is()`

Comment: Thank you for this - I like that you kept most of my code and showed me what I was missing. I'm just learning jQuery, so I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

See  http://jsfiddle.net/WGKHG/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var list = [];
        $('#add').focus();

    $('#addItem').click(function() {
        list.push($('#add').val());
        $('#add').val('');
        $('#add').focus();
    });

    $('#finish').click(function() {
        var ids=Array();
        $('#list li').each(function(){
            if($(this).find("input:checked").length>0)
            {

                ids.push( 1 * $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]);
                //alert("checked "+ids);
            }
        });

        for(var i=ids.length;i>0;i--)
        {
           //alert("checked "+ids);
           list.splice(ids[i-1],1);
        }

        $('#list').html("");

        for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) {

        $('#list').append('<li id="li_'+i+'" ><input type="checkbox" class="unchecked"/>' +list[i]+ '</li>');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MpBZp/1/

I changed the app a bit, got rid of the finsh button and list var.  Let you hit enter when you type an item in.  BTW, that JQuery is old!

Answer (score 0):

Could try binding a change event to the checkboxes that removes the item from the array when checked. Ex:

```
$("#list").on( "change", "input.checkbox", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.is(":checked") ) {
        removeFromArray( $this.val(), list );
    }
});

function removeFromArray( value, list ) {
    var index;
    if ( list == null ) {
        return;
    }
    index = list.indexOf(value);
    // Handle edge case so we dont do a range of 0 to -1
    if ( index !== -1 ) {
        list.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Haven't completely checked this code but it should be close.

Answer (score 0):

Add some id to the list by using that id remove the value from array. [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kvqsf/2/) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete solution for above issue.

**DEMO:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9n

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="text" id="add" />
  <button name="addItem" id="addItem">
    Add Item
  </button>
  <div>
    <ol id="list">
    </ol>
    <button type="button" name="lineThrough" id="lineThrough">
      Remove Checked Items
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input#add{
  border:1px solid #55669a;
}
button{
  border:1px solid #55669a;
}
button:hover{
  background:#acacac;
}
ol{
  padding:2px;
  border:1px solid #7788a9;
  background:#a2a5fd;
  display:none;
}
ol li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#add").focus();
    var list = new Array();
    //Add New Item 
    $("#addItem").click(function() {
        if ($.trim($("#add").val()) != "") {
            list.push($.trim($("#add").val()));
            $("#list").append("<li><input type='checkbox' value='" + (list[list.length - 1]) + "'/>" + list[list.length - 1] + "</li>");
            $("#add").val('');
            if (list.length > 0) {
                $("#list").show(800);
            }

        }

    });
    //Remove Checked Item
    $("#lineThrough").click(function() {
        $("#list input:checked").each(function() {
            var index = $.trim($("#list input:checkbox").index(this));
            list.splice(index, 1);
            $("#list li:eq(" + index + ")").remove();
            if (list.length <= 0) {
                $("#list").hide('fast');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9n